# How to Call Python Visualization inside Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a small web application done in `HTML/JS`. I wanted to use a Python Visualization inside in that application.

Executing Python component gives the HTML content, which I want to embedded inside the application.

How could I do this? How to call a Python Script inside JS?

Comment: Have you checked DJango?

Comment: @Lafada: No... It is entirely a Javascript application. Want to test out whether I could add a small python component in it. So I have not checked out.

Comment: If its already developed Javascript application, then Django cant help. Lets wait if any one has this type of problem solved

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to is to a have Python web microframework doing the data/HTML serving for you. Popular framework for just making tiny data-serving applications is [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

[Here is an example which serves data from Flask](https://github.com/rpazyaquian/bokeh-flask-tutorial/wiki/Rendering-Bokeh-plots-in-Flask) and then uses [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) visualization framework to do plots out of it.

[Bokeh itself has something called "plot server"](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/quickstart.html#generate-static-html-files) designed for serving plot graph data, but as I can see this is vertically integrated with Bokeh visulazation library and might not suit for your use case.